# How to create a proper dropdown toolbar item in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a macOS app written in SwiftUI where I want to add a simple drop down button with a menu to the toolbar for a view. It currently looks like this:

[image]

You can see that there is no gap between the drop down arrow and the symbol. And the icon/symbol color sometimes seems to be grayed out. When the app starts it also shows black sometimes (not constantly reproducible).

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Menu {
                        Button {
                            ...
                        } label: {
                            Text("Open cache directory")
                        }
                        .help("Show application support folder")
                        .disabled(applicationSupportDirectory == nil)
                        Button {
                            ...
                        } label: {
                            Text("Clear cache")
                        }
                        .help("Clears all content from the cache")
                        .disabled(applicationSupportDirectory == nil)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    .windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
}
```

I basically want to have a simple drop down toolbar item with a few menu items. The app is pretty new so it does not have any fancy code just yet. I wonder what I am missing. Looking forward to have a button like this:

[image]

I tried different symbols, applying padding and frame width on the Image. I tried different placements and ToolbarItemGroup. Strangely enough: When setting the toolbar style to unifiedcompact, at least the spacing works. But the colouring is still strange. Nothing helped so far.

Comment: That code looks correct. Is this on a beta version of macOS? Could it be a bug?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I'm on macOS 13.4. No Beta. Not sure if this is a bug as other apps seem to work fine. Therefore, I assume I miss something (obvious) in my code.